# Change httplib to http.client

Tags: python, httplib

I got error 'No module named httplib'. Then I replaced `httplib` to http.client. I used 2to3 and added `b` before `secret_key`.

```
import http.client
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from collections import OrderedDict
import time

server = "api.---.net"
api_key = "---"
secret_key = b"---"


def get(url):
     conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(server)
     conn.request("GET", url)
     response = conn.getresponse()
     data = json.load(response)
     return data

def post(url, params):
     conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(server)
     data = OrderedDict(sorted(params))
     encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
     sign = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=encoded_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
     headers = {"Api-key": api_key, "Sign": sign, "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
     conn.request("POST", url, encoded_data, headers)

def com():
     conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(server)
     sign = hmac.new(secret_key, b'', digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
     headers = {"Api-key": api_key, "Sign": sign, "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
     conn.request("GET", "/ex/com", None, headers)
```

Now I get error

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lc.py", line , in <module>
    COM = float(com()['fee'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: updated .  .  . .

Comment: This is a different error. So, _which_ error do you actually see: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable or Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing?

Comment: updated . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `com()` returns nothing (that is, a `None`). On return, you attempt to apply the selection operator to `None` (`['fee']`), which would work only if `com()` returned a dictionary.